# My if statement returns 0 as the length of my variable when I enter a value with length 4 but returns the correct length for all other values

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm trying to limit the values entered in one of the fields of my form to 4 digits only. If it is greater or less than 4 digits it should throw an alert and let you know that you do not have the correct number of digits (I currently have major.length in the alert so I can see what length it is determining). When I enter values with more or less than 4 digits it works and returns the correct length of the value I entered, but when I enter a 4 digit value it returns 0 as the length and thus validates my if statement and I cannot figure out why. I'm pretty new to javascript so I'm sorry for any non-optimal code.

```js
function digitCount() {
  for (i=1; i < 7; i++) {
    major = document.getElementById("major" + i.toString()).value;
    minor = document.getElementById("minor" + i.toString()).value;
    sub1 = document.getElementById("sub1" + i.toString()).value;
    sub2 = document.getElementById("sub2" + i.toString()).value;

    if (major.length != 4 || minor.length != 4 || sub1.length != 4 || sub2.length != 4) {
      alert(major.length);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tbody><tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><b>Journal Voucher</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4"><b>SRN:</b><input type="text" id="SRN" size="4" value="8010"> (4 digits)</td><td colspan="2"><b>Fiscal Month: <input type="text" id="month" size="2" value="11"> Must be 1,2,3,...12</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><b>Journal Entries</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="4"><b><center>General Ledger Account Number</center></b></td>
<td align="center" rowspan="2"><b>Transaction<br>Amount</b></td>
<td align="center" rowspan="2"><b>Description (max. 50 characters)</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><b>Major</b></td><td align="center"><b>Minor</b></td><td align="center"><b>Sub<br>Acct 1</b></td><td align="center"><b>Sub<br>Acct 2</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major1" size="4" value="1000"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor1"size="4" value="1000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub11" size="4" value="1000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub21" size="4" value="0000"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance1" size="12" align="right" value="1234.56"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc1" size="50" value="Record Store Sales"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major2" size="4" value="4000"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor2" size="4" value="1000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub12" size="4" value="0000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub22" size="4" value="0000"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance2" size="12" align="right" value="-1000.00"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc2" size="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major3" size="4" value="4000"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor3" size="4" value="2000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub13" size="4" value="0000"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub23" size="4" value="0000"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance3" size="12" value="-234.56"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc3" size="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major4" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor4" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub14" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub24" size="4"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance4" size="12"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc4" size="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major5" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor5" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub15" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub25" size="4"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance5" size="12"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc5" size="50"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="major6" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="minor6" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub16" size="4"></td><td><input type="text" id="sub26" size="4"></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="balance6" size="12"></td><td><input type="text" id="desc6" size="50"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><b>Sum of Transaction Amounts</b></td><td align="right"><input type="text" id="sum" size="12" value="0.00"></td><td> <b> (Must sum to 0.0)</b></td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Validate and Submit"></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: You apply `.toString` to the element, that should be the element's `value`.

Comment: please provide html form code

Comment: @IngoSteinke I have tried adding .toString() to my variables both where they are initialized and where I do the comparison (e.g. major.toString().length) but neither of those seem to resolve my issue.

Comment: @HiteshTripathi I just added the table

Comment: your table is not filled, up to 6 rows. what should happen with empty rows?

Comment: it's return 0 because after three row your table have blank value for  major4,major5,major6,minor4,minor5,minor6 same for subject 1 and two fields

Comment: @HiteshTripathi you are correct that was the problem! Thanks for your help! I added an additional function to fill any blank fields first.